# How to subset data in a ggplot panel chart?

Tags: r

I am trying create a panel chart in ggplot with four variables which all have their own scale for the y axis. I can get the structure of the panel chart to work but am having trouble actually getting each data set onto the gird. I have been following a script I found online. See below however I am getting the following error when I try and use the subset function further down in the script.

```
Error in .(variable == "Count") : could not find function "."

#load data
#Data source: data analysis-gullies > R Stats Input > Panel Chart
df <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
View(df)

#load library
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dfm <- melt(df, id.vars =c("Interval"))
View(dfm)

test <- ggplot(dfm, aes(Interval, value, ymin = 0,
                 ymax = value, colour = "grey20"))+ scale_colour_identity() +
                  xlim(5,1115)+ facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free", as.table = FALSE)+
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                axis.title.y = element_text())
test

test1 <- test + geom_col(subset = .(variable == "Count"))
test2 <- test1 + geom_col(subset = .(variable == "Length"))
test3 <- test2 + geom_col(subset = .(variable == "Area"))
test4 <- test3 + geom_col(subset = .(variable == "Volume"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `patchwork` package to merge individual ggplot2 objects to get individual axes for each panel:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

iris %>%
  nest(-Species) %>%
  mutate(
    plt = data %>% map2(Species, ~ {
      .x %>%
        ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_point() +
        labs(title = .y)
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(plt) %>%
  wrap_plots()
```

You can also add logic to plot different plots per panel:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

iris %>%
  nest(-Species) %>%
  mutate(
    plt = data %>% map2(Species, ~ {
      if(.y == "setosa") {
        .x %>%
          ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = .y)
        
      } else {
        .x %>%
          ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
          geom_line() +
          labs(title = .y)
      }
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(plt) %>%
  wrap_plots()
```

If the panel plots are very different from each other (e.g. different variables for the x and y axes), it is recommended to create each plot individually and then call `wrap_plots` of all the plot objects:

```
plt1 <- qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris, geom = "point")
plt2 <- qplot(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, data = iris, geom = "line")
wrap_plots(plt1, plt2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou I will give it a go. Quick question though do all the plots need to be the same type or can I have three plots using geom_col and one plot using geom_line?

Comment: I edit the answer for conditional plotting

Comment: What if I don't have a variable like species that I want to group by?  I want a plot for Volume versus Interval (which is essentially distance along a river), then the next plot would be Area versus Interval, Length versus Interval, Count versus Interval.  Each will have their own different scale. Ideally it would be 1 column, 4 rows. Does that make sense?